# Migrating from AlchemyData News to Discovery New, query with multiple entities

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

I am trying to migrate an application which was using AlchemyData News to search for News based on multiple entities in the query, for example

`&q.enriched.url.entities.entity=|text=IBM,type=Company| &q.enriched.url.entities.entity=|text=Apple,type=Company|`

The above query searches for IBM and Apple with entity type company

How do I do the same with Discovery News? The [Migrating from AlchemyData News](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/migrate-adn.html#service-comparison) article on the one hand says:

- Discovery and AlchemyData News use the same query syntax.

but also mentions:

- The query structure and the structure of data returned is different between Watson Discovery News and AlchemyData News

The Alchemy query as is doesn't work.

Per Discovery documentation the the entity search query looks something like:

`entities.text:IBM,entities.type:Company`

However I am not sure how to specify multiple entities in this query, does anyone have an idea what the query could look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you are looking for: `entities:(type:Company,(text:IBM|text:Apple))`

Which says "Give me entities where the type is Company and the text is IBM or Apple"

(I am an IBM Watson Employee)

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was looking for. However using this `entities:(type:Company,(text:IBM|text:Apple))` I only got results where the entity was IBM with no Apple results (with 25 results). I then changed the query to `entities:(type:Company,(text:IBM,text:Apple))` which  should have given the results matching both IBM and Apple, however the response had no results. Am I missing something?

Comment: When I copy the query I provided, I get 390k results with both Apple and IBM.  If I remove just IBM or remove just Apple I get a correct subset. The change you made is looking only for articles that have both entities in the same doc.  TLDR; are you copying the query exactly to the query or filter field with no others?